# Observable is canceled by flatmapped flowable error

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have the following RxJava2 chain:

```
fun refreshList() {
        refreshDisposable?.dispose()
        refreshDisposable =
                mapHandler.filtersFlowable()
                        .doOnNext{
                            Timber.w("LISTFILTER - New filter! $it")
                        }
                        .switchMap {
                            lastPage = 0
                            refreshByPage(lastPage, it).toFlowable()
                        }
                        .doOnSubscribe {
                            Timber.w("LISTFILTER - In progress")
                            listRefreshState.postValue(Result.inProgress())
                        }
                        .map {
                            Result.success(it)
                        }
                        .ioUi(schedulerProvider)
                        .subscribeBy(
                                onNext = {
                                    Timber.w("LISTFILTER - Success!")
                                    listRefreshState.value = it
                                },
                                onError = {
                                    Timber.w("LISTFILTER - Error! ${it.message}")
                                    listRefreshState.value = Result.failure(it)
                                }
                        )
                        .addTo(disposables)

    }
```

That is, i have a set of filters in my app, when you change them a new request should be thrown against the backend API.

Now I found that sometimes the request would fail, and then my filtersFlowable would stop emitting. I would expect for it to keep emitting after changing the filters again.

This is the definition of FiltersFlowable:

```
private val filterSubject: BehaviorSubject<ApplyFilterRequest> =
        BehaviorSubject.createDefault(
                if (sharedPrefsManager.getFilters().isNotEmpty())
                    ApplyFilterRequest.fromJson(moshi, sharedPrefsManager.getFilters())
                else
                    ApplyFilterRequest.allPlacesAllTypes())

private val filterFlowable = filterSubject.hide().toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
```

How can I achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`onErrorResumeNext`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators#onerrorresumenext):

```
fun provideFlowable(filter: Boolean): Flowable<Boolean> {
    val filterSubject: BehaviorSubject<Boolean> = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(filter)
    return filterSubject.hide().toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
}

fun refreshList() {
    provideFlowable(true)
        .doOnNext { println("Before switch map") }
        .switchMap { apiCall(it) }
        .doOnNext { println("After switch map") }
        .subscribe(
            { println("Success") },
            { println("Error") }
        )
}

// will throw an error if true is passed
fun apiCall(filter: Boolean): Flowable<Boolean> {
    return Flowable.just(filter)
        .map { if (filter) throw Exception() else it }
        .onErrorResumeNext { error: Throwable ->
            println("Error happens")
            Flowable.just(false)
        }
}

refreshList()
```

Comment: mmm this does not really match my code does it? or am i missing a step here?

Comment: @GabrielSanmartin It's just to give you an idea on how `onResumeNext` works. Adapt it to your code.

Comment: Well I tried but this does not achieve what i want unfortunately

Comment: finally managed to get it working using your solution thanks!

Comment: @GabrielSanmartin glad it worked. could you mark the answer as accepted for clarity purpose?